# How to make a remote WMI calls to a machine with ISA Server 2006 running?

Tags: wmi, rpc, isaserver

Whenever I try to make WMI queries from a remote machine I get an exception

> "The RPC Server is unavailable".

I did make a firewall policy rule in ISA Server to allow the protocal named "*RPC Server (all interfaces)*", From and To are "*Computer Sets/Anywhere*" and it's still blocked. I unchecked "*Enforce Strict RPC*" and still nothing.

The RPC service is running. I manually started the RPC Locator server too, to no avail.

The complete exception message is:

> The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the RPC Filter on your ISA Server:

- Run ISA Server Management.
- In the left pane, select "Firewall Policy".
- In the right pane, go to the "Toolbox" tab, then select "Protocols".
- Expand "All Protocols", then double-click "RPC (all interfaces)".
- Go to the "Parameters" tab.
- In the "Application Filters" list, uncheck "RPC Filter", then click OK.
- At the top of the screen, click "Apply".

You can also try the hotfix from [MS KB 887222](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887222), but I haven't tested that.